# posicionar elementos numa grid

Tags: html, css

estou tentando fazer uma calculadora e não estou conseguindo deixar os botões redondos ficam um pouco achatadoa, também não estou conseguindo deixar o 0 da mesma maneira que está na imagem queria saber como posicionar o 0 da mesma maneira da imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 335px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /* grid-gap: 16px; */
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 25px;
  /* font-size: 30px; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 7px 11px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 192 */

.item1 {
  background-color: #a5a5a5;
  color: black;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: #fe9e09;
}

.item3,
.item4 {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.teste {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 77px;
  margin-top: 441;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="item1">AC</div>
  <div class="item1">+/-</div>
  <div class="item1">%</div>
  <div class="item2">:</div>
  <div class="item3">7</div>
  <div class="item3">8</div>
  <div class="item3">9</div>
  <div class="item2">x</div>
  <div class="item3">4</div>
  <div class="item3">5</div>
  <div class="item3">6</div>
  <div class="item2">-</div>
  <div class="item3">1</div>
  <div class="item3">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item2">+</div>
  <div class="item4">0</div>
  <!-- <div class='item4'></div>  -->
  <div class="item3">,</div>
  <div class="item2">=</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali no seu `.item4` , crie uma regra separada e coloque:

```
.item4 {
  grid-column: span 2; 
  text-align: left !important;
  border-radius: 70px !important; 
}
```

- `grid-column: span 2;` faz com que o elemento `0` ocupe a largura de 2 elementos
- `border-radius: 70px !important;` necessario para sobreescrever a regra, mas isso não é uma boa prática. Coloquei apenas para exemplificar.
- `text-align: left !important;` como sugerido nos comentários, para ficar com o texto do `0` alinhado a esquerda.

Comment: Muito bom, faltou só um `text-align: left !important;` para ficar igual ;)

Answer (score -1):

Seu problema é em relação à propriedade `padding` do CSS, abaixo algumas orientações:

- se você adicionar só um valor, assim `padding:25px;` o valor será atribuído para todos os lados do elemento, ou seja: top, right, bottom, left, respectivamente.
- Ao adicionar 2 valores, `padding:28px 25px;` (o que fiz para funcionar), os valores serão atribuídos aos eixos y (altura) e x (largura)
- Ao adicionar 4 valores, por exemplo: `padding: 10px 10px 10px10px;` os valores serão atribuídos na ordem: top, right, bottom, left.

Você também pode atribuir os valores para cada lado ao utilizar `padding-top:28px; padding-right:25px; padding-bottom:28px; padding-left:25px;` . Ao descrever as posições você facilita a leitura mas o código também fica mais macarrônico.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 335px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /* grid-gap: 16px; */
}

.container > div {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 28px 25px;
  /* font-size: 30px; */
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 7px 11px 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 192 */

.item1 {
  background-color: #a5a5a5;
  color: black;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: #fe9e09;
}

.item3,
.item4 {
  background-color: #333333;
}

.teste {
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 77px;
  margin-top: 441;
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow: none;
  font-size: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="item1">AC</div>
  <div class="item1">+/-</div>
  <div class="item1">%</div>
  <div class="item2">:</div>
  <div class="item3">7</div>
  <div class="item3">8</div>
  <div class="item3">9</div>
  <div class="item2">x</div>
  <div class="item3">4</div>
  <div class="item3">5</div>
  <div class="item3">6</div>
  <div class="item2">-</div>
  <div class="item3">1</div>
  <div class="item3">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>
  <div class="item2">+</div>
  <div class="item4">0</div>
  <!-- <div class='item4'></div>  -->
  <div class="item3">,</div>
  <div class="item2">=</div>
</div>
```